# Kubernetes MachineDeployment - Scale down specific node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

can someone please say if it is possible to scale down specific Node on MachineDeployment? If I for example will, scale down, then Kubernetes do this with this own algorithm. I cannot google answer on this question.
I found this annotation. It should be exatcly what i will. I annotated nodes and machines and on scale down Kubernetes has decided for other nodes. Not annotated by me.
[cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine](https://main.cluster-api.sigs.k8s.io/reference/labels_and_annotations.html)

I also tried label machines and nodes with these annotations but without success.

```
#Annotations
machine.cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine
machinedeployment.cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine

kubectl annotate machine cx41-586b67669f-m7dnk machinedeployment.cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine=true -n kube-system
kubectl annotate machine cx41-586b67669f-ps6zx machine.cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine=true -n kube-system

kubectl annotate node cx41-586b67669f-ps6zx cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine=true -n kube-system
kubectl annotate node cx41-586b67669f-tcgcw cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine=true -n kube-system
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting your question.

However, I don't think it's possible to intervene by selecting which node to remove during autoscaling if you use a Cloud environment.

I say this because basically the concept of node-pool assumes that there is a set of identical nodes and therefore it would be senseless to choose which node to remove during down scaling.
For this, Kubernetes has the responsibility to "choose" and "empty" the nodes suitable for removal based on metrics.

To do what you want, you should have a set of default Virtual Machines, for example 20 VMs, where you use 10 and 10 remain "available" for scaling (with Kubernetes, the same version, already installed).
Then you have to create an automatism that, based on the metrics you prefer, executes a script/Ansible Playbook that deals with scale down/up based on the labels you have previously assigned to the nodes.

The script could be really simple in a first version... for scale-down, just run:

```
kubectl cordon -l LABEL
kubectl drain -l LABEL
kubectl delete node -l LABEL
```

For the scale-up depends on how fast you want to be... you may decide not to have the servers ready and add in the script also the provisioning phase, Kubernetes installation and join the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. cordon -> drain - will not works, because I have MachineDeployment and MachineSet. It will immediately start a new node if one is not available. And this is my problem. 
But why this annotation does not works? From the documentation - it should works! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the details.
Let's have a look here: https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/api/v1alpha3#MachineSetList ; https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api/issues/75 ; https://medium.com/@wintonjkt/machinesets-and-auto-scaling-openshift-cluster-a24c458a200a

Is it possible that you miss configuring the "MachineSetDeletePolicy"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to annotate the **machine** using `cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine=true` but as per this [**source**](https://www.debuggingmode.com/tanzu/tkg/cluster-lifecycle-management/tkg-scale-down-node/)(author @Shubham Sharma), we need to give the annotation value as `yes` like this `cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine=yes`. So try changing the value of annotation and scale down the **machinedeployment**.

```
$ kubectl annotate machine <machine-name> "cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine"="yes"
```

After annotating the machine scale down the **machinedeployment** and see that the selected **node** is deleted or not.

```
$ kubectl scale machinedeployment <machinedeployment-name> --replicas=2
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Yes i saw this moment and tried too. "yes" does not works too.

Comment: Can you try this `$ kubectl annotate machine <machine-name> cluster.x-k8s.io/delete-machine = <node-name> `.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I will try it later. Suddenly, my test cluster is in working mode already,

Comment: Hi @JDev did you get a chance to test it ? is it useful?

Comment: Hi @Dharani, sorry but no. I do not have test cluster at this time, maybe in couple of weeks. I will answer you here.

Comment: HI @JDev Did you get a chance to validate it?

Comment: Hi. @Dharani. Nope, sorry.